# Insterting an int value into a char type pointer

Tags: c, pointers, memory, char, int

So I want to do a custom memory allocator where you basically input a certain size of bytes and it creates a huge arena of N bytes. Everything is working fine except that i need to input an int and display it as 4 bytes into hex. For example:

If i have :

```
unsigned char* char_pointer = (unsigned char*)malloc(4*sizeof(uint8_t));
int value = 500;
for(int i =0 ; i<8;i++){
   printf("%02X ", *(char_pointer+i))
}
```

So this will display

```
00 00 00 00
```

So far so good.
But if I want to do this for example:

```
*char_pointer = value;
```

It will display

```
F4 00 00 00
```

What I really want to be displayed is this:

```
F4 01 00 00
```

For the value of the int is 500 which is 1F4 in hex. How would I go over this?

Comment: You loop over 8 bytes and show only 4. You might check your code. "value of the int char is 500" There is no such thing as an `int char`.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I just realized my mistake. I wanted to say the value of the int. Thank you for pointing this out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is cast to char. Try

```
*(int*)char_pointer = value;
```

Optionally you can write bytes explicitly:

```
*(char_pointer+0) = *(((char*)(&value))+0)
*(char_pointer+1) = *(((char*)(&value))+1)
*(char_pointer+2) = *(((char*)(&value))+2)
*(char_pointer+3) = *(((char*)(&value))+3)
```

Comment: You just saved my life. Thank you so much. I have one more thing to ask, though. How would I go about reading the value from there to an int? So *(int*)char_pointer = value; worked. And now it displays F4 01 00 00 but what if I want to get that value back into another int? If i simply write int new_int = *char_pointer It will give me another number since, i suppose, it only reads the first byte.

Answer (score 1):

In this statement : `*char_pointer = value;`

Type of lvalue and rvalues are not matching . `unsigned char` can hold upto `255`.

Compiler will do [implicit typecasting](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Computer_Programming/Type_conversion) here. 
So only one byte will be copied into memory area pointed by `char pointer` .

I am showing a dirty non-portable way to perform what you want:

`*((unsigned int*)char_pointer) = value`

Answer (score 1):

Use `memcpy()` and let a good compiler optimize it.

```
unsigned char* char_pointer = malloc(sizeof value);
memcpy(char_pointer, &value, sizeof value);
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use `*char_pointer = value;` if the `value` is greater than 255.

You will have to come up with an algorithm to assign the pointers.

e.g.

```
tempvalue = value;
for (i=0; i<4; i++)
{
    char_pointer[i] = (char) tempvalue;
    tempvalue /= 256;
}
```

Comment: Your result depends on endianess.

Comment: The problem statement requires little endian